# Need a single php regular expression for three different lines of text?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following 3 lines of text and need a single regular expression to capture only the data. The data can contain any characters.  The line with the word test can be (test1|test2|test3|test4)

```
1. test1 data- data 
1. data- data
data- data
```

Here's what I tried to do but not working.

```
   $remove_test_name = "(?:test1|test2|test3|test4)";

   preg_match("/(?:\d+\.)? $remove_test_name (.*)\-(.*)/",$string,$matches);
   echo $matches[1] . "-" . $matches[2];
```

The output I'm getting is this for line 1 (mention above):

> :test1 data

for line 2

> :data

for line 3

> :

What I would like is this:

> data: data

Comment: Could you elaborate on the input format, it's unclear where `test1`, `test2`, etc appear.

Comment: test1 or test2 or test3 or test3 appears after the line number. Some line numbers don't have test1 or test2 or test3 or test4

Comment: I -think- I've edited your question so your sample file text shows up properly... Please confirm.

Comment: thanks CanSpice, your edit is correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s the PHP and samples I’m using to test the regex.

```
<?php
$sample = array(
    '1. test1 data- data ',
    '12. data- data',
    'key- value',
    '2. test2 key2- value2',
    '3. test3 data- data ',
    '4. test4 data- data ',
    '5. test5 data- data '
);

foreach ($sample as $string) {
    $remove_test_name = '(?:test1|test2|test3|test4)';

    preg_match("/(?:\d+\.)?\s?$remove_test_name?\s?(.*)-(.*)/",$string,$matches);
    var_dump($matches);
    echo $matches[1] . "-" . $matches[2];
}
?>
```

Here’s the output

```
array
  0 => string '1. test1 data- data ' (length=20)
  1 => string 'data' (length=4)
  2 => string ' data ' (length=6)

data- data

array
  0 => string '12. data- data' (length=14)
  1 => string 'data' (length=4)
  2 => string ' data' (length=5)

data- data

array
  0 => string 'key- value' (length=10)
  1 => string 'key' (length=3)
  2 => string ' value' (length=6)

key- value

array
  0 => string '2. test2 key2- value2' (length=21)
  1 => string 'key2' (length=4)
  2 => string ' value2' (length=7)

key2- value2

array
  0 => string '3. test3 data- data ' (length=20)
  1 => string 'data' (length=4)
  2 => string ' data ' (length=6)

data- data

array
  0 => string '4. test4 data- data ' (length=20)
  1 => string 'data' (length=4)
  2 => string ' data ' (length=6)

data- data

array
  0 => string '5. test5 data- data ' (length=20)
  1 => string 'test5 data' (length=10)
  2 => string ' data ' (length=6)

test5 data- data
```

In the last case test5 shows up because it's not in `$remove_test_name`.

Comment: thanks Herbert for getting this almost working. The only other problem is that test1-4 still shows up in the output. Somehow its part of capture 1 ($matches[1])

Comment: Are you matching line-by-line or the whole thing at once?

Comment: I'm matching line by line. Here's the latest I tried and still not working. preg_match("/(?:\d+\.)?\s*?$remove_test_name?\s*?(.*)-(.*)/",$string,$matches);

Comment: @bruce: I edited my answer to show the code I used to test it and the var_dump on each line. What am I missing or misunderstanding?

Comment: a tricky problem. I changed to code to this and it now works preg_match("/(?:\d+\.)?\s\s(?:test1)?\s*(.*)-(.*)/",$string,$matches); I had two whitespaces between the line number and test1 so having it \s*? made it not greedy

Comment: this solved the problem -> preg_match("/(?:\d+\.)?(?:\s*)?(?:test1)?(?:\s*)?(.*)-(.*)/",$string,$matches);

Comment: If any of our answers helped, you should accept one. It will show others (looking at future questions) that you accept answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the input is the columns that are separated by a dash, and there are no other dashes in the input.  So something along the lines of: `/(\s*(.*)\s*-){2}\s*(.*)\s*/` should do.

Comment: thanks mazzz, did not work, I only get the output of :  . I used echo $matches[1] . "-" . $matches[2];

Comment: did you do a var_dump of the matches array?